# Extending the SelectArrayInput component

Tags: admin-on-rest

I need to modify the `SelectArrayInput` component so that it is linked to an object array field instead of an array of foreign keys.

The API I am using returns response for resources includes fields that contain object arrays, for example:

```
tags: [{id, name, description},...]
```

What is the recommended manner to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
import { SelectArrayInput, ReferenceArrayInput } from 'admin-on-rest'

<ReferenceArrayInput source="tag_ids" reference="tags">
    <SelectArrayInput optionText="name" />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

Be aware that you will have to add clean "tags" resource under the `<Admin>` component in you App.js file.

```
const App = () => (
    <Admin restClient={jsonServerRestClient('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')}>
        <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
        <Resource name="tags" />
    </Admin>
);
```

Check the last section of `SelectArrayInput` with `ReferenceArrayInput` here: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#selectarrayinput

Update me if it works.